Do I need an exhaust fitting for an RV diesel heater in the garage exiting through cinder blocks?
I am planning to install a heater in my garage. I am seeing that some users use this fitting but this is just 3" deep so I don't think it will make it through the blocks.
Is it OK to just drill a hole and then push the exhaust through it ? I am thinking that nothing is going to be set on fire but the wall will get cold/hot/cold/hot and in the end probably the cinder blocks might crumble of crack.


Maybe keep looking.  Most through the wall thimbles should be deeper.  The one for my pellet stove is at least 6 inches deep/8 inches round for one piece(for 3 inch insulated chimney/exhaust).  TEMU is probably not the most trust worthy place to shop for this.

Same stuff everywhere. Produced in China sold with various margins everywhere

DO NOT INSTALL THIS THING
Based on numerous red flags (if I was a bull I'd be running like crazy...) I would not trust this particular device indoors under any circumstances, and even outside I would treat it with extreme caution.
Burning stuff creates bad things. In the case of natural gas, that is mostly water and carbon dioxide but some other stuff as well, and proper exhaust to the outside is needed. In the case of diesel or gasoline, there is a lot more to be concerned about.
Generally speaking, gasoline or diesel generators are supposed to be on the order of 20 feet or more from any window or door to an occupied building, for very important reasons. A gasoline or diesel heater is no different - do not put inside unless truly designed for inside use and with proper exhaust to the outside and fire safety considered properly as well.
On top of all the general concerns, this device looks like a typical large Asian country designed/manufactured item with little concern for modern safety standards.
No, just no.

with all due respect you should calm down a little bit. Let me guess, are you in the HVAC industry which would charge an arm and a leg for their services ?
You might want to know that this is designed and sold as RV heater.  There is carbon monoxide detectors which I will use. These are chinese copies of a German brand (Webasto?) and the design is not THAT complicated that they would fail in copying at an average quality. There is tens of thousands of users (just to count those who post on Youtube and who post reviews on Amazon) who are using these

No, I am a computer programmer who dabbles in my own home repairs (I will do some non-computer things for other people, but not 120V or higher electrical or anything involving natural gas). And I am not actually so concerned about the heater failing to work. I am very concerned about you using a cheap chinese copy of a device that burns diesel inside a vehicle or building. Carbon monoxide is one concern. Another is carbon dioxide (if you don't think that can be dangerous, research Apollo 13 among others). Another is fire. I just wouldn't trust it.

would you feel better if this would be installed outside and just the hot air pipe will be connected to the garage ?

Yes that would be much safer.

This particular device is pretty sketchy, but fundamentally there is no practical difference between a permanently mounted diesel space heater and an oil-fired water boiler, which is something that is installed in millions of homes. Or a wood stove, fireplace, or any propane/natural gas appliance.

@nobody A permanently mounted diesel space heater with sufficient input air and proper exhaust ventilation would be fine. Propane/natural gas burns a whole lot cleaner than diesel so I would trust those much more. But in all cases a certain amount of proper design and installation is required - and I'm really skeptical here.
